# Asp.Net Razor View Passing Expression To Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I find myself writing this a whole lot in my views:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.City)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.City)
</div>
```

I'd really like to put this in a Partial `_Field.cshtml`, something like this:

```
@model //what model type???

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(Model)
    @Html.EditorFor(Model)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model)
</div>
```

That could then be called by:

```
@Html.Partial("_Field", x => x.City)
```

What would the `@model` type in my partial be if I wanted to accomplish something like this?

**UPDATE** This works, but I'd rather use a partial for ease of changing the template:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Field<TModel, TItem>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> expr)
{
  var h = "<div class='form-group'>";
  h += $"{html.LabelFor(expr)}{html.EditorFor(expr)}{html.ValidationMessageFor(expr)}";
  h += "</div>";

  return MvcHtmlString.Create(h);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. However, what you want is very similar to editor templates. Essentially, you just create a view in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` named after one of the following conventions:

- A system or custom type (String.cshtml, Int32.cshtml, MyAwesomeClass.cshtml, etc.)
- One of the members of the `DataType` enum (EmailAddress.cshtml, Html.cshtml, PhoneNumber.cshtml, etc.). You would then apply the appropriate `DataType` attributes to your properties:

  ```
  [DataType(DataType.EmailAdress)]
  public string Email { get; set; }
  ```
- Any thing you want, in conjunction with the `UIHint` attribute:

  ```
  [UIHint("Foo")]
  public string Foo { get; set; }
  ```

  Which would then correspond to a Foo.cshtml editor template

In your views, then, you simply use `Html.EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.City)
```

Then, for example, you could have `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml` as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessage("")
</div>
```

*(The empty quotes are placeholders. Razor will automatically fill in the appropriate property name, thankfully.)*

Calling `EditorFor`, then, will print all of this, rather than just the default text input. You can take this much further, as well. I have [some](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/) [articles](http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/) on my blog that goes into greater detail, if you're interested.

**UPDATE**

It's worth mentioning a few features of `EditorFor`:

1. You can pass a template directly to the call, meaning you can customize what template is used on the fly and per instance:

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.City, "MyCustomEditorTemplate")
   ```
2. You can pass `additionalViewData`. The members of this anonymous object are added to the `ViewData` dynamic dictionary. Potentially, you could use this to branch within your editor template to cover additional scenarios. For example:

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.City, new { formGroup = false })
   ```

   Then in your editor template:

   ```
   @{ var formGroup = ViewData["formGroup"] as bool? ?? true; }
   @if (formGroup)
   {
       <!-- Bootstrap form group -->
   }
   else
   {
       <!-- Just the input -->
   }
   ```

Comment: I considered using `EditorTemplates`, but the problem is I use them all over the place, but dont *always* want them wrapped with the extra div etc, I dont always want a Label. I guess I could create UIHint based templates for everything and use _ViewStart to reduce html. Going to sit on this.

Comment: See my update above. Might give you something to work off of.